# Esri Javascript API 4 Print Widget not printing graphics?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I am using the Esri Javascript API 4.3 api and have added a Print Widget to my webmap.

My map contains a few PictureMarkerSymbols that are displaying just fine on my map but when I export the map using the print widget, the symbols do not show up. I have tried replacing the PictureMarkerSymbol with a SimpleMakerSymbol and teh behavior is the same.

Can anyone help ?

Comment: Have you tried with the recently released version 4.4 of the JSAPI? If it's still a problem, could you share an example - see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: actually I resolved that issue by making my PictureMarkerSymbols accessible from a public url. Once that was done, the print task worked and my markers appeared on the exported image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved that issue by making my PictureMarkerSymbols accessible from a public url. Once that was done, the print task worked and my markers appeared on the exported image. Hope this helps someone